# /bin/bash: no: command not found: when trying to use a make:model command with J.DepP

Tags: c++, bash, compiler-errors

**When trying to run a Makefile from [J.DepP](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Eynaga/jdepp/#feat), I keep getting /bin/bash: no: command not found. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is there a `no` program to install?**

```
// Command that fails (split into 2 lines for readability)
find /home/jdepp-2015-10-05/KNBC_v1.0_090925/corpus1 -type f -name "KN*" | LC_ALL=C sort | xargs cat | 
no /home/jdepp-2015-10-05/tools/knbc2kyoto.py KNP | no /home/jdepp-2015-10-05/tools/replace_pos.py /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/mecab -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/mecab/dic/unidic > model/knbc/train.JDP.euc

/bin/bash: no: command not found
/bin/bash: no: command not found
xargs: cat: terminated by signal 13
make: *** [Makefile:948: knbc] Error 127
```

That is the error I'm getting, where it's trying to run the `no` command. When I type `no` in terminal, it doesn't exist. Line 948 of the Makefile is just the command above.

Has anyone successfully installed `J.DepP` and fixed this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually an issue because python wasn't installed and J.DepP's makefile didn't return a fail for a critical dependency.

Install python, run `make clean && ./configure` and the issue with disappear.